# Why does not 'while(csv.Read())' work two / three times in CsvHelper?

Tags: .net-core, csvhelper

I use the CsvHelper and I have the problem, I want to go over the rows as much as I have headers(columns) in a file and in every step does some specific logic in the `while` section. However, after the first circle, I can't go into the `while` and I don't have any idea how to fix it or how to maybe refresh the reader rows counter?

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
  var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
  {
    Delimiter = ";",
  };

  using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
  {
    for (var col = 1; col < headers.Length; col++)
    {
      while (csv.Read())
      {
        //do some logic
      }
    }
  }
}
```

have anyone an idea,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should switch your `for` and `while` statements.  You need to read the row first and then loop through the columns.

```cs
void Main()
{
    using (var reader = new StringReader("Id,Name\n1,One\n2,Two"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        var headers = csv.HeaderRecord;
        
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            for (var col = 0; col < headers.Length; col++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(csv.GetField(col));               
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```